# How Rhino-Mocks mocks?

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks

I would like to know how Rhino-Mocks finds out which method I want to stub. The example below stubs the method `GetUserByName`:

```
var stubUserRepository = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IUserRepository>();
stubUserRepository.Stub(x => x.GetUserByName("ayende")).Return(theUserObject);
```

In the example below I just forward a delegate to the Framework.

I think it is using method signature. Am I right?

Is it using reflection? If yes, how?

Where I can look for it? How it works?

I am using C# and the moment.
I would like to know the concept behind and the C# applied stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Stub` call sets up an optional `Expect` call. The function passed to `Stub` (`x => x.GetUserByName("ayende")`, in this instance) is actually executed against the mock object (which is a [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) object). The call is intercepted and recorded in the `MockRepository`, with its parameters, as an expectation. An `IMethodOptions<>` object is generated from data saved about the call and returned, which `Return(theUserObject)` is subsequently called on.

You can use something like [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to disassemble and examine Rhino.Mocks.dll in more detail; the relevant code is in `RhinoMocksExtensions.cs`, in the `Rhino.Mocks` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to the great Chris's answer [the link to Rhino Mock source code](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks)